# How to mock an axios class

Tags: javascript, redux, jestjs, axios, moxios

I am writing tests for my asynchronous actions. I have abstracted away my axios calls into a separate class. If I want to test my asynchronous redux action, how do I write a mock for `api.js` so that `sampleAction.test.js` will pass? Thanks!

**api.js:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

let apiUrl = '/api/';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/';
}

export default class Api {
  static async get(url) {
    const response = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}${url}`, {withCredentials: true});
    return response;
  }
}
```

**sampleAction.js:**
    import Api from './api';

```
export const fetchData = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await Api.get('foo');
    dispatch({
      type: 'RECEIVE_DATA',
      data: response.data.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error);
  }
};
```

**sampleAction.test.js:**

```
import store from './store';

test('testing RECEIVE_DATA async action', () => {
  const expectedActions = [
    { type: 'RECEIVE_DATA', data: 'payload' },
  ];
  return store.dispatch(actions.fetchData()).then(() => {
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/axios/moxios?

Comment: Thanks @CharlieStanard, I did take a look at it. I see it referencing mocking an axios.create() instance, however, I'm just left pretty confused on if that is the kind if thing I should be using for a mock, and how to do so. I mean, if I called that mock, what would happen? Don't I want it to mock the url passed into it and return a certain value?

Comment: Alternately see https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mock `Api.get` like this:

```
import { fetchData } from './sampleAction';
import Api from './api';

let getMock;
beforeEach(() => {
  getMock = jest.spyOn(Api, 'get');
  getMock.mockResolvedValue({ data: { data: 'mock data' } });
});
afterEach(() => {
  getMock.mockRestore();
});

test('testing RECEIVE_DATA async action', async () => {
  const dispatch = jest.fn();
  await fetchData()(dispatch);
  expect(getMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');  // Success!
  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    type: 'RECEIVE_DATA',
    data: 'mock data'
  });  // Success!
});
```

---

...or you can mock `api.js` like this:

```
import { fetchData } from './sampleAction';
import Api from './api';

jest.mock('./api', () => ({
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: { data: 'mock data' } }))
}));

test('testing RECEIVE_DATA async action', async () => {
  const dispatch = jest.fn();
  await fetchData()(dispatch);
  expect(Api.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');  // Success!
  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    type: 'RECEIVE_DATA',
    data: 'mock data'
  });  // Success!
});
```

---

...or you can auto-mock `api.js` and fill in the return value for `Api.get`:

```
import { fetchData } from './sampleAction';
import Api from './api';

jest.mock('./api');  // <= auto-mock
Api.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: { data: 'mock data' } });

test('testing RECEIVE_DATA async action', async () => {
  const dispatch = jest.fn();
  await fetchData()(dispatch);
  expect(Api.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');  // Success!
  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    type: 'RECEIVE_DATA',
    data: 'mock data'
  });  // Success!
});
```

---

...or you can create a [manual mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) at `./__mocks__/api.js`:

```
export default {
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: { data: 'mock data' } }))
}
```

...and activate it in your test like this:

```
import { fetchData } from './sampleAction';
import Api from './api';

jest.mock('./api');  // <= activate manual mock

test('testing RECEIVE_DATA async action', async () => {
  const dispatch = jest.fn();
  await fetchData()(dispatch);
  expect(Api.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');  // Success!
  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    type: 'RECEIVE_DATA',
    data: 'mock data'
  });  // Success!
});
```

Comment: Thanks @brian-lives-outdoors, this is fantastic!